# Get all combinations of elements in array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need an algorithm to get all the possible combinations of elements in a multi dimensional array of values.  Something similar to a permutation.

The loop in the array must go both ways.

For example,

`var arr= [[1],[2],[3],[4]];`

would produce a result of

`[1,2]`
`[1,3]`
`[2,3]`
`[3,4]`
`[4,3]`
`[3,2]`
`[2,1]`

Comment: Why `[1, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2]` are not there?

Comment: @thefourtheye I think that's sample o/p user posted

Comment: So that means you need permutations of all possible sizes?

Comment: Brute force way: Use a double loop, i.e a loop inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4], result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j += 1) {
        if (i !== j) {
            result.push([arr[i], arr[j]]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 1, 3 ],
  [ 1, 4 ],
  [ 2, 1 ],
  [ 2, 3 ],
  [ 2, 4 ],
  [ 3, 1 ],
  [ 3, 2 ],
  [ 3, 4 ],
  [ 4, 1 ],
  [ 4, 2 ],
  [ 4, 3 ] ]
```

Comment: `for/in` is for iterating over the enumerable properties of an object, you should use a vanilla `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)` loop if you choose this approach.

Comment: Thanks.  What I was looking for.  Sorry thefourtheye, for your initial question it was a typo on my part.  I did this early this morning on fly well I was still half asleep lol.