# Algorithm to generate all combinations of a string with length n to 1

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I am looking for help with an algorithm that will generate all the possible combinations of n-random letters in decreasing length. For example, the array of 'a','b','c' should generate:

abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
ab
ac
ba
bc
ca
cb
a
b
c

where letters cannot repeat themselves once used

Comment: Please make an honest attempt at the problem before asking here.

Comment: I've looked through NPM for any solutions and none of them handle a situation that produces combinations in decreasing length. I've attempted my own, but nothing efficient comes to mind, besides potentially removing the first element in an array, regenerating combinations and then removing the first again...

Comment: Before trying any code please study permutation and combination. It will help you lot.

Comment: @VipulHadiya I've have, but neither deals with decreasing lengths of permutations for every possible subset of letters

Comment: Can you generate subsets out of the whole set? Yes. Can you write a for loop that goes from `n` to `1` in decreasing order? Yes. All that remains is generating the permutations.

Comment: If you want to cut to the chase: [*https://gist.github.com/axelpale/3118596*](https://gist.github.com/axelpale/3118596). Also see answers at [*Javascript, all possible sums of an array members (up to 4)*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557888/javascript-all-possible-sums-of-an-array-members-up-to-4/27558192#comment43546411_27558192)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Permutation with decresing length" is basically just a loop  of standard permutation task.:

- you are given a set of n letters
- take each letter and add it to the output
- take all possible pairs of letters and add them to the output
- take all possible triplets of letters and add them to the output
- ... do until you reach N

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. This makes sense. Was having trouble breaking it down into smaller problems.