# How do I make a combination with Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, combinations

How do I make all possibilities in a loop?

Example ; `a,b,c`

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

for/next, for each or do/while? with Classic ASP

Comment: did you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561212/algorithm-to-generate-all-combinations-of-a-string-with-length-n-to-1

Comment: Have you actually sat down with a pencil and paper to have a think about the process?  It's very logical and very easy.